# Chrome driver is not working on azure web apps

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver, azure-web-app-service

I have used .NetCore2 App and try to takes the screenshot of given URL. It works perfect on local but After deploy to Azure have problems on create Webdriver.

```
 at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService..ctor(String servicePath, Int32 port, String driverServiceExecutableName, Uri driverServiceDownloadUrl)
↵   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService..ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port)
↵   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
↵   at SceenshotApp.Service.Screenshot.TakeScreenshot(String url, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 delay) in D:\Projects\TFT\Bitbucket-Linkury\Website\Tools\ScreenshotAPI\DotNetCore\SceenshotApp\SceenshotApp\Service\Screenshot.cs:line 21
↵   at SceenshotApp.Controllers.HomeController.TakeScreenshot(String url, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 scale, Int32 delay) in D:\Projects\TFT\Bitbucket-Linkury\Website\Tools\ScreenshotAPI\DotNetCore\SceenshotApp\SceenshotApp\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 51"
```

below my code

```
 public static string GetScreenshot(string url)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options);
        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 768);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();
        return path;
    }
```

How can I use Chrome driver on Azure?

Comment: Due to azure web app sandbox, the selenium is not supported on azure web app.

Comment: @Ivan Yang : thanks for reply, any alternatives ?

Comment: It's not a good solution, but it can work if deploys to azure vm.

Comment: my path is under Nuget package Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver

Comment: @Dimitar : I'm using  var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options);

Comment: Can you post the full exception (currently it's a bit cutted) stack trace ?

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException
The file D:\home\site\wwwroot\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService..ctor(String servicePath, Int32 port, String driverServiceExecutableName, Uri driverServiceDownloadUrl)
↵   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService..ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port)

Comment: its not working even not works on local

Comment: @Dimitar, you should test it yourself then answer the op. And as per the [azure web app sandbox limitation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks), it's not supported.

Answer (score 6):

As @IvanYang said, `Selenium` is not supported on Azure App Service for Windows, as the figure below from [`Azure Web App sandbox`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

[image]

The reason is [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions)

[image]

However, you can try to deploy your .net core app to Azure App Service on Linux, which be based on docker image.

So you can follow the quick start tutorial [`Create an ASP.NET Core app in App Service on Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-dotnetcore) to migrate your current app for Linux. And due to `Selenium` requires headless chrome, you must have to install `chromium` or `chrome` or their headless distributions and webdriver in the docker image or write in the Dockerfile first, please refer to the offical document [`Tutorial: Build a custom image and run in App Service from a private registry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image) to know it.

As reference, there are many blogs which helps for you and you can search via Google/Bing, such as [`Selenium in Docker with DotNetCore Chrome in Linux and Headless Mode`](https://medium.com/devpassis/selenium-in-docker-with-dotnetcore-chrome-in-linux-and-headless-mode-993ba422ebcf).

Hope it helps.