# Why does puppeteer not work on azure webapp

Tags: node.js, screenshot, puppeteer, azure-web-app-service, takesscreenshot

I have used Nodejs and try to takes the screenshot of given URL. It works perfect on local but After deploy to Azure have problems on create puppeteer.

**Code**

```
exports.getScreenShot = async function (req, res) {
    const requesturl = req.param('url');
    if (!requesturl) {
        return res.send(400, 'Missing url');
    }
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(requesturl);
    if (!parsedUrl.protocol) {
        return res.send(400, 'Invalid url, missing protocol');
    }
    if (!parsedUrl.hostname) {
        return res.send(400, 'Invalid url, missing hostname');
    }

    const options = {
        'width': req.param('width'),
        'height': req.param('height'),
        'delay': req.param('delay'),
        'userAgent': req.param('userAgent'),
        'full': (req.param('full') === 'true')
    };

    options.width = options.width || 1024;
    options.height = options.height || 768;
    options.delay = options.delay || 200;    
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: 'wss://chrome.browserless.io/'
    });

    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(requesturl);
    await page.waitFor(parseInt(options.delay));
    let imageName = parsedUrl.hostname.replace(/\W/g, '_');
    let pathName = parsedUrl.pathname.replace(/\W/g, '_').replace(/_$/, '');
    if (pathName) {
        imageName += pathName;
    }
    imageName = `${imageName}.png`;
    var tempPath = temp.path({ suffix: '.png' });
    await page.setViewport({ width: parseInt(options.width), height: parseInt(options.height) });
    await page.screenshot({
        path: tempPath,
        fullPage: options.full
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Refer to the SO Tag Info for [`puppeteer`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/puppeteer/info), as below.

> Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control **headless Chrome** or **Chromium** over the DevTools Protocol. It can also be configured to use full **(non-headless) Chrome or Chromium**.

Whatever Chrome or Chromium with headless or non-headless, they all require GDI support. However, on Azure App Services on Windows, it conflicts with [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions), as the figure below.

[image]

And other frameworks like `PhantomJS/Selenium` also be restricted by it, see below.

[image]

So you can not use puppeteer within Azure WebApp on Windows. The workaround solution is to use Azure VM or Azure WebApp on Linux. Essentially, this issue is duplicated with your other SO thread [Chrome driver is not working on azure web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105911/chrome-driver-is-not-working-on-azure-web-apps).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe it doesn't work on Azure WebApp on linux either. If it does for you, that is great news. Would you be willing to share more details about your setup on linux?

Comment: Can confirm that this does not work on linux either as @MarkoPrcać suggested.

Comment: i am trying in linux and it still does not work, tried headless, other options

Answer (score 3):

[How to run Headless Chrome in Azure Cloud Service or Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806116/how-to-run-headless-chrome-in-azure-cloud-service-or-azure-functions)

Replace puppeteer.launch with puppeteer.connect. See the code below:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: 'wss://chrome.browserless.io/' });
```

Comment: Browserless.io is pretty cool, it's free for a small number of requests/per day and then has usage based pricing options.  This was a great solution for my use case.